# how to send mail to multiple users using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

How can we send the mail to multiple users using node.js program?.I tried this program. I got an error. I posted the error below. Can anyone solve this error?

```
ERROR OCCURED:
{ Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 74.125.200.108:465
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '74.125.200.108',
  port: 465,
  command: 'CONN' }

NODE.JS PROGRAM:


var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'vignesh.mack03@gmail.com',
        pass: '************'
    }
});
var mailOptions = {
    from: "vignesh.mack03@gmail.com",
    subject:"DIFFERENT EXPERIENCE" ,
    text: "This IS viki I sent this email using node.js program .This is really different experience",
    to: "vikirockz456@gmail.com,vigneshbv02@gmail.com"
};
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This basically indicates a connection issue, Could be due to firewall,

Can you try connection to gmail smtp from the same machine & to the same port 465, but via a different application.
Say via openssl

`openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`

Comment: firewall is in enable state only. I added  in transporter variable like                                                  
    host: 'smtp.example.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,        where I can use that    openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465`, On the same machine you are facing the above issue, It would help to identify whether or not the machine is able to connect to the gmail smtp server. Use it in your command line